# Cannot find the "main class" installing my own snap

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

I started working with Ubuntu Core and Snaps a few days ago. I've managed to finish [the very basic tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/create-first-snap?utm_source=snapcraft.io&utm_medium=buildsnapsindex&utm_campaign=tutorials#0) about creating my own snap and everything worked perfect.

Now it's time to go further, so for bigger purposes I tried to create my own Hello World snap. My idea is to code a Java daemon for printing "hello world" right and backwards, using the StringUtils library just for the need of adding some maven dependencies, and downloading the code from a GitLab private repository.

The java code worked fine on my computer so I went for the snapcraft.yaml:

```
name: java-maven-hello
version: 0
summary: A java example using maven dependecies
description: this is not much more than an example
confinement: devmode
grade: devel

apps:
  daemon:
    command: java -cp basic-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar es.ramadorp.odm.snapcraft.test.daemon.Daemontest
    restart-condition: always 
    daemon: forking

parts:
  daemon:
    plugin: maven
    source: http://gitlab.ramadorp.es/ramador/snap-maven-test.git
```

Time to run snapcraft and no problems so far, but when I try to install the delivered snap I get:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Start snap "java-maven-hello" (unset) services ([start snap.java-maven-hello.daemon.service] failed with exit status 1: Job for snap.java-maven-hello.daemon.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

The "systemctl status snap.java-maven-hello.daemon.service" gives me:

```
● snap.java-maven-hello.daemon.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since lun 2017-04-24 10:23:54 CEST; 4min 34s ago

abr 24 10:22:24 Bec systemd[1]: Starting Service for snap application java-maven-hello.daemon...
abr 24 10:22:24 Bec /usr/bin/snap[8670]: cmd.go:111: DEBUG: restarting into "/snap/core/current/usr/bin/snap"
abr 24 10:22:24 Bec snap[8670]: Error: Could not find or load main class es.ramadorp.odm.snapcraft.test.daemon.Daemontest
abr 24 10:22:24 Bec systemd[1]: snap.java-maven-hello.daemon.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
abr 24 10:23:54 Bec systemd[1]: snap.java-maven-hello.daemon.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
abr 24 10:23:54 Bec systemd[1]: Failed to start snap.java-maven-hello.daemon.service.
abr 24 10:23:54 Bec systemd[1]: snap.java-maven-hello.daemon.service: Unit entered failed state.
abr 24 10:23:54 Bec systemd[1]: snap.java-maven-hello.daemon.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

So, I understand the installation is not finding the `.jar` to execute?, but I went deep on the folders created by snapcraft and the `"basic-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"` is there, in `/home/bec_1/wkf/snapmaven/parts/daemon/build/target`. My knowledge doesn't go much far to understand if the .jar location is right or why the installation is not finding the "main class". Any ideas? 
By the way, my `pom.xml` file looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.boundedinfinity</groupId>
    <artifactId>basic-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to specify the path to the jar file when launching it. Something like this:-

```
    command: java -cp $SNAP/basic-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar es.ramadorp.odm.snapcraft.test.daemon.Daemontest
```

Comment: Thanks! now I can install the snap, but it's not working yet. I add the $SNAP like you said but I when I try to execute the snap I receive "command not found". Am I still pointing wrong? I also tried to add the route like:

– java -cp $SNAP/home/bec_1/wkf/snapmaven/prime/jar/basic-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and more variations, just in case (trial and error), and nothing.